# Understanding parameters interaction contrasts in model averaging

Tags: mean, model, contrasts

I am struggling to understand how parameter interaction contrasts play into model averaging. As I am new to Stack Exchange, I apologize if my question is in the wrong place or incorrectly asked. I will adjust as needed. I have found very few sources for understanding this topic, so any insight or directions to sources would be invaluable.

I am interested in assessing the effects of the hypothetical set of parameters: *C*, *D*, *E*, and *F*. Think of *CDEF*, *CD + EF*, and *C + D + E + F*, or the lack of them as four different ways of trying to understanding the system. To be clear, these combinations are not contrasts, but are representations of unique, related parameters. They're  different ways of looking at the system! *A* and *B* are used to absorb variation and are not the focus of my hypotheses.

In R Studio, I have coded them as generalized linear models with a logit link. The response variable is binary, 0 or 1.

The modeled formulations are as follows:

| Model | Formulation |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A + B |
| 2 | A + B + CDEF |
| 3 | A + B + CD + EF |
| 4 | A + B + C + D + E + F |
| 5 | A * B |
| 6 | A * B + CDEF |
| 7 | A * B + CD + EF |
| 8 | A * B + C + D + E + F |

I would like to model average the estimates of the individual *C*, *D*, *E*, and *F* parameters using the other formulations. For example, when model averaging the estimate of *C*, I would average across the estimates from the other models: 0 from model(s) 1 and/or 5, *CDEF* from model(s) 2 and/or 6, *CD* from model(s) 3 and/or 7, and *C* from model(s) 4 and/or 8. The averages would be weighted using the Akaike weights as specified in Burnham & Anderson (2002).

I have read that model averaging across models with differing contrasts yields 'nonsense' results. (See quote below). I would like to understanding if this is still the case if the parameters with the differing contrasts (*A* and *B*) are not the estimates being averaged (variations of *C*, *D*, *E*, and *F*).

From the model.avg function's [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/MuMIn/man/model.avg.html):

> Averaging models with different contrasts for the same factor would yield nonsense results. Currently, no checking for contrast consistency is done.

**Does it make sense to model average across all eight model formulations if the contrasts for *A* and *B* differ but I'm only interested in averaging the estimates for *C*, *D*, *E*, and *F*?**

**Would it make more sense to select the four models of the same *A* and *B* contrast with the lowest AIC values (1-4 or 5-8) and model average across only the four?**

Thank you for your time and guidance!